# What value we need to pass for placing order in programatically for cash on delivery?

Tags: magento2, cash-on-delivery, place-order

I want to **place order programmaticall**y using **cash on delivery** method for COD.

What value I need to pass? please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign by `cashondelivery`

Something like this

```
$quote->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery');

$quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'cashondelivery']);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();

$quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($quote->getId());
$order = $this->cartManagementInterface->submit($quote);
```